# Sorting from two text files c

Tags: c

I have two sorted sequences one on data1.text another one in data2.txt both contains 20 sortet numbers. I need to create code sort.c that reads numbers from both txts and at the same time compares them and outputs smaller one in sort.txt , so it is kinnda merging sort)

that is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv1[],char *argv2[],char *argv3[])
    {

        char *f1 = argv1[1];// taking filename1 from args
        char *f2 = argv2[1];// taking filename2 from args
        char *f3 = argv3[1];// taking filename2 from args
        FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;

        fp1 = fopen(f1,"r");
        fp2 = fopen(f2,"r");
        fp3 = fopen(f2,"w");// sort.txt file so 'w'
        int num1,num2;
        fscanf (fp1, "%d", &num1);
        fscanf (fp2, "%d", &num2);
        while (!feof(fp1) && !feof(fp2)) {
        if (num1<num2)
            {
                fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",num1);// print num 1
                fscanf (fp1, "%d", &num1);  // read num1
            }
            else{
                fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",num2);
                fscanf (fp2, "%d", &num2);  // read num2
            }
        }

         if (!feof(fp1))
         {
            while (!feof(fp1))
            {
                fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",num1);// print num 1
                fscanf (fp1, "%d", &num1);  // read num1
            }
         }
            else
            {

                while (!feof(fp2))
                {
                    fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",num2);
                    fscanf (fp2, "%d", &num2);  // read num2
                }
            }


        fclose(fp1);// closing file f1
        fclose(fp2);// closing file f2
        fclose(fp3);// closing file f2

        return 0;
}
```

it shows segmentation fault =(

Comment: `int main(int argc,char *argv1[],char *argv2[],char *argv3[])` I reckon you are not looking for an argument?

Comment: so i should write ./sort.c data1.txt data2.txt sort.txt and it should read first and second and write on third

Comment: No, the prototype for main is `int main(int c, char *v[])` or equivalent. `v` is an array of pointers to strings; you won't need the extra arguments, just index the array `v[]` to find all the arguments, they have been put there for you to use. Isn't C great? BTW: `if (!feof(fp1)) {}` is terribly wrong.

Comment: You should be checking that `fopen()` works each time; also that each `fscanf()` works.  You'll probably survive without them in a tame environment, but the real world of programming is hostile and your code would die very quickly out there.

Comment: What you've coded is a simple merge (and given that the input files are sorted, that's fine).  You can simplify the tail code by using two loops: `while (!feof(fp1)) { ... }` followed by `while (!feof(fp2)) { ... }`.  But you would run into problems if there was an alphabetic character in either input file.  You should be checking `while (fscanf(fp1, "%d", &num1) == 1) { fprintf(fp3, "%d\n", num1); }`.  No muss, no fuss, and no infinite loops on bad data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main` is wrong. Should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.
Then instead of

```
    char *f1 = argv1[1];// taking filename1 from args
    char *f2 = argv2[1];// taking filename2 from args
    char *f3 = argv3[1];// taking filename2 from args
```

something like

```
    char *f1 = argv[1];// taking filename1 from args
    char *f2 = argv[2];// taking filename2 from args
    char *f3 = argv[3];// taking filename2 from args
```

but before these lines you should check `argc` for correct number of arguments.
You probably meant `fp3 = fopen(f3,"w");` instead of `fp3 = fopen(f2,"w");`.

Comment: so ifter i wrote  ./sort.c data1.txt data2.txt sort.txt it works but sort.txt is empty...